# Nvidia Opengl symlinks

Tags: debian, symlink, nvidia, opengl

Last NVidia update in the Debian unstable branche (375.82) broke the symlinks of the openGL libs.

LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo|grep

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so

libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  48
  Current serial number in output stream:  47
```

sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so

```
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libGL.so.1
```

I have no experience with symlinks and I can't find this problem online solved without using docker or installing the bin version. The latter would break my CUDA/Tensorflow setup due to libs not being compatible with the .bin version.